# Where is NMon cron job for AIX?

Tags: cron, performance, aix

While trying to know where is NMon job configured to run; I do find that it's **NOT** listed on Crontab (using `crontab -l`).

**BUT** - the job is currently running as expected, which is weird.
See the following output for `ps`

```
server# ps -ef | grep nmon
root 67043538   1   0 00:01:32 -  0:00 /usr/bin/topas_nmon  -x -F /usr/local/log/server.nmon -tA -s 180 -c 480 -youtput_dir=/usr/local/log/server.nmon -ystart_time=00:01:31,Dec20,2014
```

So? where it's configured to be executed; there must be another place rather than `crontab`.

My server is running **AIX 6.1**
- Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Found that AIX handles it via `smitty topas`.
Interesting.

Comment: `smitty topas` apparently calls (at least in AIX 7) `/usr/lpp/perfagent/config_aixwle.sh`, which then manages cron entries that call `/usr/bin/topasout`.